# How to get rid of Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C?

Tags: c, malloc

I have a very simple implementation of a buffer with writing and reading index in C.
Below is the .c file and then after the main().

Cant see why but I'm getting the Segmentation fault (core dumped).

The .c file is below.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "contbuf.h"

typedef struct cont_buf
{
    char *buf;
    ln_bsize size;
    int read_index;
    int write_index;
    int has_data;
} cont_buf;

cont_buf *create_cont_buf(ln_bsize *size)
{
    cont_buf *cb;
    cb->buf = malloc(sizeof(float)*(*size));
    if(cb->buf == NULL){
        printf("Failed to get or allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
        }
    cb->size = *size;
    cb->read_index = 0;
    cb->write_index = 0;
    cb->has_data = 0;

    if (!cb->buf)
        return NULL;

    return cb;
}

void free_cont_buf(cont_buf *cb)
{
    free(&cb->buf);
}

void write_float_to_cb(cont_buf *cb, float *f)
{
    if ((cb->write_index + 1) > cb->size)
    {
        cb->write_index = 0;
    }

    cb->buf[cb->write_index] = *f;
    cb->write_index += 1;

    if (cb->write_index > cb->has_data)
        cb->has_data = cb->write_index;
}

void read_float_from_cb(cont_buf *cb)
{
    float f;
    f = cb->buf[cb->read_index];
    printf("float number: %f\n", f);
}
```

And here is the main() file, just to teste the functions in the C.

There is also a .h file that I'm not sharing but it is just declaration of the functions and typedefs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "contbuf.h"

    int main() {
    
        struct cont_buf* cb;
        ln_bsize* size;
        *size = (ln_bsize)20;
        float *f;
        *f = 3.25F;
    
        cb = create_cont_buf(size);
    
        write_float_to_cb(cb, f);
    
        read_float_from_cb(cb);
    
        return 0;
    
    }
```

Could someone help me to figure out why ? I also don't find a way to troubleshoot since the run doesn't even run, so I cannot tell when the code breaks.

Comment: `n_bsize* size; *size = (ln_bsize)20;`

Answer (score 1):

You have a primary issue in

```
    ln_bsize* size;
    *size = (ln_bsize)20;
```

here, `size` does not point to any valid memory location, yet to you try to dereference it and put value into the memory location pointed by it. This is invalid memory access which invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To avoid this, you need to ensure that `size` points to valid memory location. For this case, you can avoid the problem by not making `size` a pointer type altogether. Just do

```
 ln_bsize size = 20;
```

and then, pass it to the function like

```
  cb = create_cont_buf(&size);
```

You have the problem of using /dereferencing uninitiated memory in many other places of the code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  cont_buf *cb;
>  cb->buf = malloc(sizeof(float)*(*size));
> ```

*cb* is not initialized but you dereference it, the behavior is undefined

> ```
>    ln_bsize* size;
>    *size = (ln_bsize)20;
> ```

same thing about *size*

I encourage you to take into account the warnings produced by the compiler, and to ask for the more possible  using option like `-Wall` or  better `-Wall -Werror` if using gcc

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to allocate memory for where `cont_buf *cb` and `ln_bsize* size` should point to.

`cb` and `size` are just pointers. Their intent is to point to objects of the respective types.

The attempt to initialize any members of a structure like at `cb->buf = malloc(sizeof(float)*(*size));` or to initialize the referenced object `*size = (ln_bsize)20;` invokes undefined behavior.

Allocate memory for where they should point to:

```
cont_buf *cb = malloc(sizeof(cont_buf));
if (!cb)
{
    fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

and

```
ln_bsize* size = malloc(sizeof(ln_bsize));
if (!size)
{
    fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to malloc the "char *buf" dynamically (according to the function parameter size) ? but no the full struct ?